# Unterschied zwischen »dazu« und »zudem«

Tags: difference

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen *dazu* und *zudem?* Ich sah beide Wörter während des Lesens und glaube, dass kein Unterschied zwischen diesen besteht. Ist das richtig?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beide Wörter sind Adverbien. *Zudem* hat genau eine Bedeutung, welche von *dazu* ebenfalls abgedeckt wird. Letzteres ist aber etwas universeller einsetzbar, da es noch einige weitere Bedeutungen hat.

Die gemeinsame Bedeutung ist *außerdem*. [Der Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zudem) definiert *zudem* als gehoben und nennt *[noch] dazu* als Synonym von *zudem*.

Beispiel aus dem Duden:

> Es war kalt und regnete zudem [noch].

Die Bedeutung ist *neben dem einen [=Kälte] ist auch das andere wahr [=Regen]*. Man kann auch sagen: *Es war kalt und außerdem regnete es auch noch.* Hier kann *zudem* durch *dazu* ausgetauscht werden. Meinem Sprachverständnis nach muss hier das Pronomen *es* aber hinzugefügt werden.

> Es war kalt und es regnete dazu.

Die weiteren Bedeutungen von *dazu* sind *zu diesem Zweck* beziehungsweise *hinsichtlich dieser Sache*.

> Wir haben den Bewerber abgelehnt. Er eignet sich nicht dazu.
>
> Wir haben die Angeklagte befragt. Sie wollte sich dazu nicht äußern.

Answer (score 1):

Hier können die beiden nicht ausgetauscht werden:

> Ich möchte ein Bild an die Wand hängen. Dazu benötige ich einen Hammer.
>   Aber vielleicht sollte ich das nicht selbst machen, denn ich bin sehr ungeschickt. Zudem ist das Bild äußerst wertvoll.

Comment: Im letzten Satz kann *zudem* durch *dazu* ersetzt werden. Man muss zwar den Satz leicht ändern, aber nur weil zwei Wörter synonym sind, heißt es ja nicht, dass die Satzkonstruktion identisch sein muss. Also mein Vorschlag ist: *Dazu kommt [noch], dass das Bild äußerst wertvoll ist.*

Comment: @Em1: Oder auch *Noch dazu ist das Bild äußerst wertvoll.*

Answer (score 1):

Beide Wörter unterscheiden sich maßgeblich und sollten *nicht* synonym verwendet werden. In den seltenen Fällen, in denen dies möglich wäre (wie im hier zitierten Beispiel von Em1), ist *zudem* stilistisch stets die bessere Wahl.

> Es war kalt und regnete zudem.
>
> Es war kalt und es regnete dazu. (*noch dazu*: überdies - on top of it)

**zudem** ist eine adverbiale Konjunktion, die durch *außerdem* ersetzt werden kann, jedoch nicht in der Bedeutung von *besides*, sondern nur im Sinne von **in addition**. Es wird überwiegend wertneutral verwendet und verbindet zwei Tatbestände gleichwertig miteinander.

Die Bedeutung von **dazu** ist immer sehr eng verbunden mit der Präposition *zu*:

Ein Beipiel aus dem Restaurant:

> Es werden Kartoffeln und **zudem** Reis angeboten. (gleichwertig / ich kann wählen)
> Es werden Kartoffeln und **dazu** Reis angeboten. (der Reis ist Beilage)

**dazu** hat meist die Funktion eines Pronomens für ein Präpositionalobjekt:

> Ich möchte einen Fernseher kaufen. **Dazu** lasse ich mich beraten. (zu diesem Zweck)
>
> **Dazu** sage ich nichts mehr. Ich habe keine Lust auf eine lange Diskussion und *außerdem* (habe ich) keine weiteren Argumente.
>
> **Zu dem Thema** sage ich nichts mehr. Ich habe keine Lust auf eine lange Diskussion und **zudem** keine weiteren Argumente.

Answer (score 0):

*Zudem* hat die gefühlte Bedeutung von *außerdem*, *zusätzlich*, *hinzukommend*.

Comment: Und was ist mit "dazu"?

Comment: Ebenfalls gefühlt, eher die Bedeutung von hierfür oder befügen, nicht das betonende von "zudem"

Comment: Warum pflegst du sowas nicht in deine Antwort ein? Es wird nach dem Unterschied gefragt, bisher beantwortest du aber nur, welche Bedeutung *zudem* hat. PS: Lass noch das Wort *gefühlt* weg, denn *zudem* hat keine Nebenbedeutungen, sondern eine klare Aussage, nämlich: *Zusätzlich zu dem bereits genannten.*